# "Unable to open (file)" [psftp]

Tags: psftp

First things first this probably isn't a permission issue. You can check the image to see that for the most part I have permission to read & write at all levels of directories leading up to the file and the file itself.

[image]

The problem likely isn't the permission on the folder I am sending it two as I had created a new folder on the remote server to send the file to. Outside of that I am a bit stumped

Answer (score 6):

Is it your LOCAL permissions rather than the REMOTE permissions. Try and create a new (temp) folder locally, lcd to that and try from there.

Comment: Could be also an issue of a non-elevated cmd.

Comment: When I started PSFTP the local director was 'C:\Windows\system32' which wasn't a great place to copy things...